# Can we use only arithmetic operator to make this true

Tags: mathematics

Can we use only arithmetic operators (no digits) to make this true?
11 11 11 = 6

Comment: I guess we're not allowed to separate an `11` into `1` and `1`?

Comment: Can you specific exactly what counts as arithmetic operators? Just $+,-,\times,\div$?

Comment: any kind of arithmetic operator: log, e, cos, +, !, ...

Comment: You need to give a clearly defined list of which operators are allowed, otherwise it's not really answerable. I could define a new arithmetic operator $\star$ such that $11\star11\star11=6$ and make it trivial.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is similar to Dmitry Kamenetsky's answer. Here I'm assuming I can use any mathematical operators:

> As $3 \lt \sqrt{11} \lt 4$, We know that $\left \lfloor{\sqrt{11}}\right \rfloor = 3$
> Therefore $\left \lfloor{\sqrt{11}}\right \rfloor * \left \lfloor{\sqrt{11}}\right \rfloor - \left \lfloor{\sqrt{11}}\right \rfloor = 3 * 3 - 3 = 6$
> With no additional digits in sight.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but

> We can do it in binary:
>  $11_2*11_2-11_2 = 3*3-3 = 6$

Comment: no digit allowed!

Comment: But they are not digits. They are just a way to write it in a different base.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Using [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm):

> $$\log^*(11) + \log^*(11) + \log^*(11) = 6$$
>  Note: $\log^*(11) = 2$

---

### Solution 2

Here is another solution using [Multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) and $\log$.

> $$11!!!!!!\ /\ 11 + \log_{11}(11) = 6$$
>  Note:
>  $11!!!!!! = 11 \cdot (11-6) = 55$
>  $\log_{11}(11) = 1$

I hope the base in the $\log$ can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to eyl327's answer, multifactorial can be quite powerful:

> $11 - 11!!!!!!/11 = 11-5 = 6$

or

> $11!!!!!/\gcd(11,11) = 6$, where gcd is used to deal with the remaining 11.

Also,

> because  $.\overline{11} = 1/9$,
>  $(11!!!!!!!!!/11!!!!!!!!)/.\overline{11} = \frac{2/3}{1/9} = 6$